# Defining System Use Cases of a Windows Service application

Tags: uml, use-case

Unsure if this is the right place to ask such question.

I have to define use cases for a Windows Service application and I have some issues.
It regards a Windows Service application that is programmed to perform some tasks periodically.

One of the use-cases is "The system looks up unpaid orders and sends reminder to customer".

Alistar Cockburn's definition of an Actor: "An actor is anyone or anything with behavior."

My questions now are:

1) In my scenario, who is the Actor or Actors?
2) Who are the stakeholders / interests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not Mr. Cockburn, but...
Actor should be anyone (or anything) who comes into touch (/uses) with system. <= Easier definition for me.

1.) So in your case, customer should be actor.
2.) I was always creating use cases with just use cases and actors.. what are stakeholders and interests? They are imo just another actors. If not, it just adds complexity to tool, which should be simple. (IMO)

Btw: Is `"The system looks up unpaid orders and sends reminder to customer".` really a use case? Isn't that a *scenario* (part of a use case)?

Edit: Use cases should describe behaviour from end user point of view. So it really should be something like:

```
Scenario: Pay for order  
Actor: Customer  
Flow:  
1. Customer requests unpaid orders from system (not specifing how).  
2. System provides (shows) unpaid orders.  
3. Customer chooses one order  
4. System process selection and shows detail about selected order  
5. Customer requests to make a payment (again not telling something like 'customer will click on button called "pay"')  
6. System requests payment details from user  
7. User fills details  
8. System validates entered data  
9. IF successful:
    a.) Order payment is comleted, system redirects user to XXX.
10. ELSE go back to step 7
```

It might be a bit long... but that's basically how I am doing scenarios (which are grouped into one use case).

Comment: Ok and according to you, who are the Actors in case of "The system updates the status of paid orders"?

Comment: Nobody, there is just a system. And this also seems like step in a scenario to me.

Comment: I have added an example of scenario to my answer.